# Citeauthor{authors} not working as stated in the documentation

Tags: natbib

I am using `natbib` package for my citations and whenever I try to cite just the first author I always get et. al. after like

`\Citeauthor{authors}` give me `Author et al, xxxx` instead of `Author`.

I would like to have Author and co-workers for this citetation.

Accordingly to the official documentation it should print just Author.

This is my preamble

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,english,oneside]{report}
\usepackage[square]{natbib}
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: The documentation doesn't state that. Since the first author didn't do the job alone, you should use *et al.* to appreciate the co-authors.

Comment: Not clearly but looking at the documentation I understand that you can actually format the citation as you like! regardless if the author did it alone or with et al

Answer (score 4):

To achieve your objective of mentioning the names of all authors of a given entry, you should use the "starred" variant of the command, i.e.,

```
\citeauthor*
```

(note the asterisk), and not `\citeauthor` (without the asterisk).

A full working example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@techreport{acemoglu-autor-etal:2014,
  title        = "Return of the {Solow Paradox}? {IT}, Productivity,
                  and Employment in {U.S.} Manufacturing",
  author       = "Daron Acemoglu and David Autor and David Dorn and
                  Gordon H. Hanson and Brendan Price",
  institution  = "National Bureau of Economic Research",
  type         = "Working Paper",
  series       = "Working Paper Series",
  number       = 19837,
  year         = 2014,
  month        = "January",
}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage[square,authoryear]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\begin{document}
\citeauthor*{acemoglu-autor-etal:2014}

vs. 

\citeauthor{acemoglu-autor-etal:2014}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score -1):

Sorted with opening the .bbl file and editing the `\bibitem[Author et~al., xxxx]` with `\bibitem[Author and co--workers, xxxx]`.

Of course, this works only if the author is cited only once.

I am glad I can keep citing the co-workers!

G

Comment: A better answer lies in using `\citeauthor*` instead of `\citeauthor`. Editing the bbl file by hand will make *all* citation callouts of this piece use the full list of authors...